# Calculate powers with addition only

Tags: assembly, x86

and we were given a task which I can't figure out how to do. 
The task goes something like this:

To make a loop which is counted by `CX` and to calculate the power of 2^`CX` 
for example: If I put 5 in `CX` I get 2^5.

The instruction was to do it only with addition and to store the result in AL while using `LOOP,ADD,MOV` only.

I was only able to get to 2's multiplication.

Here's what I have tried

`MOV AL,2
 MOV CX,5
 CALC:
 ADD AL,AL
 LOOP CALC`

Comment: So what did you try? Do you know what is power of 2? What is 2^5? What is the result for cx=0? cx=1? cx=2? Any pattern?

Comment: Hint: if you do `a = a + a`, then the result is `2^1*a`. If you do it again, you have `2^2*a`. etc. I'm sure most here would know an answer, but you should first show what you have tried (edit your question and paste the code into it). Otherwise, you won't learn anything.

Comment: Nested loops are your friend.

Comment: @user: See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now you have some code, but it does not give you the right value yet (it probably gives you `64`). You should start with `1`, so `AL + AL = 2`, then `4`, etc.

To be more specific:

```
        MOV     AL,1
        MOV     CX,5
CALC:
        ADD     AL,AL        ; 1+1=2, 2+2=4, 4+4=8, 8+8=16, 16+16=32=2^5
        LOOP    CALC
```

Comment: Oh, I see, at the code I posted above, the result was 40h meaning 64 decimal. Is there any logic explanation why AL should start with one?

Comment: @user6219654: Yes, there is. Your first loop should result in 2, and that is 1+1, not 2+2. In other words, you start with 2^0=1.